# check screen orientation with configChanges

Tags: android, screen-orientation, android-orientation

I am using `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"` so that activity does not start again when screen rotation changes from landscape to portrait and vice versa.

I have some code idea so I will solve my problem but for that Is there anyway by which I can check screen orientation `onCreate()` of the activity though I am using confidChanges with orientation ???

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
    int orient = display.getOrientation(); 
    switch(orient) {
        case Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT:
            if(!oAllow) {
                    setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
            }
            break;
        case Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE:
            if(!oAllow) {
                    setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getResources().getConfiguration().orientation` in any place to know what is the orientation of the screen.

And, override `onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)` to handle orientation changes while running activity

**Updated:**
From [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ConfigurationChanges):

> In some special cases, you may want to bypass restarting of your activity based on one or more types of configuration changes. This is done with the android:configChanges attribute in its manifest. For any types of configuration changes you say that you handle there, you will receive a call to your current activity's onConfigurationChanged(Configuration) method instead of being restarted.

Comment: I am already using getResources().getConfiguration().orientation , and checking its value onCreate() but It does not affect anything when changing screen rotation.

Comment: `android:configChanges="orientation"`, putting that in the configuration file avoids the system to destroy your activity. Instead it invokes the `onConfigurationChanged(Configuration)` method. Thus `onCreate()` won't be called again. Handle the configuration changes in `onConfigurationChanged(Configuration)` only

Answer (score 0):

Please Check this it will detects the screen orientation you no need to mention it in manifest you can get the orienation.

```
 OrientationEventListener _orientaion = new OrientationEventListener(
            MainActivity.this) {

        @Override
        public void onOrientationChanged(int arg0) {
            System.out.println("Wortking");
        }
    };
    _orientaion.enable();
```

i think this will helps you.

Comment: but if I am not using ScreenSize in manifest then It is restarting activity which I don't work.